# How to read CDC from Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have gone through several resources mentioned in http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/cdc.html

The only thing mentioned about reading the CDC is that it is fairly straightforward with a link to https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/e31e216234c6b57a531cae607e0355666007deb2/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLogReplayer.java#L132-L140

This is way too high level.

Can someone please explain or provide me the code to read CDC data after enabling this feature in Cassandra?